# Uninterrupted catch block for Interruptedexception

Tags: java, class, interrupted-exception

I have written the following java code for runnable approach for creating new thread and getting errors as given below after the codes. If anyone can help me sort out this thing would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

The errors are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey! Write the code here, don't post pictures.

Comment: dont take me wrong just clarifying . r u not able to view the pic or not able to understand it through imagaes? @akuzminykh

Comment: The code needs a lot of improvement , remove Thread creation from constructor .. FYI, you have linked images which we have to click to see the code, not helping

Comment: line 22 it is not system it is System, you can't have same method with same signature in one class, and where the variable thread is coming from from also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the upper and lower case of the class names. That way, "thread" becomes "thread." Also use thread#currentthread, not thread#currentthread, this method does not exist. The same goes for thread#sleep and the constructor.

**Example:**

```
public final class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();

    Thread executingThread = new Thread(this, "Demo-Thread");
    executingThread.start();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Also it is not possible to have a method 2 times in one class. So remove a run method. Also, next time I ask you to use the codeblock and no images.

Comment: thank u for the help. it is really appreciable that u did show interest for a downvoted question. but yeah ur answer was helpful.